# Invalid deployment descriptor web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans-8

Whenever I create a new servlet on netbeans 8.0.2 it shows, Invalid deployment descriptor web.xml

And there is a cross sign on web.xml too.

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
 version="3.1">
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: post your web.xml so we can try to help.

Comment: look at line number 10 in web.xml, seems invalid.

Comment: While creating a new servlet, It doesn't let me create a new servlet instead displays a message i.e. invalid deployment descriptor web.xml

Comment: Is that really it? Is the final `</web-app>` really missing?